# Does Narasimha Avatara occur in Vishnu Purana?

Tags: vishnu-purana, narasimha

I read in Google groups that it doesn't. Can anyone with access to Vishnu Purana verify this?

Answer (score 8):

Narasimha Avatara is mentioned in Vishnu Purana but it is not described in detail.  You can see index of Vishnu Purana [here](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/visnu-purana-IDF373/).

Sage Parashara said Lord Vishnu would appear as Narasimha and would kill Prahlada's father. Lord Vishnu manifested before Prahlada and granted him that he would get Moksha. Thereafter Parashara said Lord Vishnu killed Hiranyakashipu.

*[Chapter 20](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/visnu-purana/chapter-20/topic-1), book 1 of Vishnu Purana* says (translated by Horace Hayman Wilson)

> इत्युक्त्वान्तर्दधे विष्णुस्तस्य मैत्रेय! पश्यतः। 
> स चापि पुनरागम्य
> ववन्दे चरणौ पितु:।।२९।। 
>  तं पिता मूर्द्धन्युपाघ्राय परिष्वज्य च
> पीडितम्!
>  जीवसीत्याह वत्सेति बाष्पार्द्रनयनो द्विज। ३० । 
> प्रीतिमांश्चाभवत् तस्मिन्ननुतापी महासुरः।
>  गुरुपित्रोश्चकारैवं
> शुश्रूषां सोऽपि धर्म्मवित्॥ ३१॥ 
> **पितय्र्युपरतिं नीते
> नरसिंहस्वरूपिणा।** 
>  विष्णुना सोऽपि दैत्यानां मैत्रेयाभूत पतिस्ततः॥
> ३२॥
>  ततो राज्यद्युर्ति प्राप्य कर्मशुद्धिकरीं द्विज। 
> पुत्रपौत्रांश्च सुबहूनवाप्यैश्वर्य्यमेव च॥ ३३॥ 
> क्षीणाधिकारः स यदा
> पुण्यपापविवर्जितः। 
> तदासौ भगदद्यानात् परे निर्वाणमाप्तवान्॥ ३४॥
>
> Thus saying, Visnu vanished from his sight, and Prahlada repaired to
> his father, and bowed down before him. His father kissed him on the
> forehead', and embraced him, and shed tears, and said, "Dost you live.
> my son?" And the great Asura repented of his former cruelty, and
> treated him with kindness; and Prahlada, fulfilling his duties like
> any other youth, continued diligent in the service of his preceptor
> and his father. **After his father had been put to death by Visnu in
> the form of the man-lion**. Prahlada became the sovereign of the
> Daityas; and possessing the splendours of royalty consequent upon his
> piety, exercised extensive sway, and was blessed with a numerous
> progeny. At the expiration of an authority which was the reward of his
> meritorious acts, he was freed-from the consequences of moral merit or
> demerit, and obtained, through meditation on the deity, final
> exemption from existence.

Comment: This makes no sense.  Why would Prahlada's father be put to death AFTER he repented of this former cruelty?  Looks like an interpolation to square the Vishnu Purana with other puranas that furnish all the  details.

Comment: At any rate - it looks like the "almost immortality" boon that was defeated by the narasimha avatara is totally absent in Vishnu Purana.

Comment: It's not possible to find objectively interpolations in any Purana (not just Vishnu Purana).

Comment: "It's not possible to find objectively interpolations in any Purana (not just Vishnu Purana)." @The Destoyer.  In this case it is clear.  In this purana Prahlada's father didn't receive boons as to how he may be killed and there was no need to take the man-lion avatara.  And it also says he was killed AFTER he repented which makes no sense whatsoever.  The man-lion story must have become famous and it must have been felt that Vishnu Purana cannot totally ignore it.  And perhaps because of the gruesomeness of the act the writers just briefly mention it.

Comment: Someone commented that after 2000 years there will be Gandhi or a Modi Purana. Avatar occurs when time arrives. Some Puranas occur when man chooses so.   Some Puranas get corrupted when man chooses so.